# Xamarin Forms Syncfusion - Async databinding not working with SfCombobox

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I have an issue on binding a collection into my SfCombobox when the data comes from an async call ( my api ). Of course, all works correctly with a local list.

I already check the data coming from my api and the binding with my viewmodel property all is working.

Here the XAML sample :

```
  <border:SfBorder
                        Grid.Row="4"
                        BorderColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference CategoryCombo}, Path=IsFocused, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}, ConverterParameter=0}"
                        Style="{StaticResource SfBorderStyle}">
                        <combobox:SfComboBox
                            AllowFiltering="True"
                         x:Name="CategoryCombo"
                         Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}"
                         DataSource="{Binding Categories}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id"
                             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    </border:SfBorder>
```

and the full view model

```
 [Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
    [DataContract]
    public class SearchPageViewModel: BaseViewModel
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Category> categories;
        private readonly ICategoryQueriesServices categoryQueriesServices;

        public ObservableCollection<Category> Categories
        {
            get { return this.categories; }
            set
            {
                if (this.categories == value)
                {
                    return;
                }

                this.categories = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private Category selectedCategory;

        public Category SelectedCategory
        {
            get
            {
                return selectedCategory;
            }

            set
            {
                if (selectedCategory != value)
                {
                    selectedCategory = value;
                    this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }


        public SearchPageViewModel(ICategoryQueriesServices categoryQueriesServices)
        {
            this.categoryQueriesServices = categoryQueriesServices;
        }

        protected override void CurrentPageOnAppearing(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            base.CurrentPageOnAppearing(sender, eventArgs);

            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var categories = await this.categoryQueriesServices.GetCategoryModelsAsync();
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    Categories = new ObservableCollection<Category>(categories);
                });
            });
        }

    }
```

thanks for your help